# Why is Excel 2013 encoding my Hyperlink URLs?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, redirect, html-encode, asciiencoding

I generated a large list of hyperlinks in an HTML file for a client to use. He copied all those hyperlinks into a spreadsheet (.xlsx) for efficiency's sake, but when he clicks on the links from Excel 2013, it [encodes the URL](http://s22.postimg.org/arob0uvxt/2015_01_28_11_11_53.png) (all "/" symbols replaced with "%2f"), which makes the navigation fail. Opening the hyperlinks via the html file works fine; only the Excel file does this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is he copying "all those hyperlinks into a spreadsheet"? Do any "paste special" options bypass the encoding?

Comment: @AronFoster, I considered that as well, but after typing in one of the hyperlinks manually to see if it could be a paste problem, it still sends the browser an encoded URL.

Comment: You're saying that in Excel 2013, if you manually type a hyperlink, it gets html encoded? I'm unable to reproduce.

Comment: The encoded url is a redirect from a login request? Maybe he should login before copying the urls to the Spreadsheet ?

Comment: @corn3lius, you are right, I didn't even notice the "/login.aspx?"... /facepalm. If the user is _not_ logged in when they click the hyperlink, it works (after they successfully log in). However, if they are already logged in, it _still_ generates the redirect URL and ends up redirecting to the home page rather than the redirect location.

So the question is... why is it not detecting that the user is already logged in, and why is it redirecting to the home page if the user is _already_ logged in?